# ValueError: Boolean array expected for the condition, not object

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, indexing, scikit-learn

I am trying to build a classifier with sklearn and get the following error in my console when I run my code.

```
ValueError: Boolean array expected for the condition, not object
```

I tried tweaking my data (filling in null values) as well as playing with reshaping properties (however to no avail).

Here is the relevant code

```py
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.externals import joblib

# Get the dataset
dataset = pd.read_csv('master_info_final_v12_conversion.csv')

# Split the dataset into features and labels
X = dataset[dataset[['Happy', 'Stress', 'Eyes']]]
y = dataset[dataset['phenotype']]

# Split the dataset into training and testing data
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y)

# Build the classifier and make prediction
classifier = DecisionTreeClassifier()
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
prediction = classifier.predict(X_test)

# Print the confusion matrix
print(confusion_matrix(y_test, prediction))

# Save the model to disk
joblib.dump(classifier, 'classifier.joblib')
```

Here is a snapshot of my data:

| name | rating | phenotype | Happy | Stress | Eyes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| tommy | 7.1 | boy | 56 | 23 | 19 |
| jill | 2.3 | girl |  | 74 | 57 |
| carlos | 4.4 | neither | 45 |  |  |

Answer (score 3):

This error most commonly occurs when you try to select columns using a dataframe. For example, in the OP, an entire dataframe (instead of a list/array of column names) is used to select columns, which is throwing this error.

```py
X = dataset[dataset[['Happy', 'Stress', 'Eyes']]]  # <----- error
X = dataset[['Happy', 'Stress', 'Eyes']]           # <----- no error
```

Note that many `pd.DataFrame` methods such as `select_dtypes()`, `filter()`, `query()`, `take()` etc. return a dataframe, so use the result as is; don't use it to filter the dataframe again.

```py
df.select_dtypes('int')       # <--- already dataframe
df[df.select_dtypes('int')]   # <--- ValueError: Boolean array expected

df.filter(['col1'])           # <--- already dataframe
df[df.filter(['col1'])]       # <--- ValueError: Boolean array expected
```

Another case is when you call `where()` without a boolean condition. For example,

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 2, 3], 'col2': ['a', 'b', 'c']})
df.where(df['col2'])                               # <----- error
df.where(df['col2'] == 'a')                        # <----- no error
```

In fact, if we look at the [source code](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/main/pandas/core/frame.py#L3719-L3720), when you pass a dataframe to `__getitem__` (i.e. `[]`), as in the first case, `where()` is called, so both cases boil down to the same part of the code.